# Multiple row headers using Axlsx in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, axlsx

When I tried to add multiple row headers to an excel in rails using Axlsx gem,  I am able to make scenario 1. But, what I required is scenario 2, how do I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `merge_cells`method and center the cell itself horizontally and vertically.

```
require 'axlsx'

package = Axlsx::Package.new

package.workbook do |workbook|
  workbook.add_worksheet name: 'merged_cells' do |sheet|

    # define your styles
    center = workbook.styles.add_style :alignment => { :horizontal => :center, :vertical => :center }

    # fill the cells
    sheet.add_row %w(A B C C), :style =>[center, center, center, center]
    sheet.add_row %w(A B E F), :style =>[center, center, center, center]
    sheet.add_row %w(A B G H), :style =>[center, center, center, center]

    # merge cells
    sheet.merge_cells "A1:A3"
    sheet.merge_cells "B1:B3"
    sheet.merge_cells "C1:D1"

  end
end

package.serialize 'merged_cells.xlsx'
```

To spare some space, instead of:

```
sheet.add_row %w(A B C C), :style =>[center, center, center, center]
```

you could rewrite that to:

```
sheet.add_row %w(A B C C), :style => [center]*4
```

or even to:

```
sheet.add_row %w(A B C C), style: [center]*4
```